# Bug ao reordenar lista de componentes React

Tags: javascript, lista, react, react-dom, jsx

Tenho um componente que carrega uma lista de componentes `<ComponenteReordenavel>` que é reordenado de acordo com o gosto do usuário. O bug acontece quando eu modifico o `style` desse componente e mando reordenar novamente, o `style` sempre fica no componente da posição em que foi modificado e não no componente que eu apliquei o `style`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Debugando

Após debugar a aplicação percebi que o erro acontece porque react atualiza apenas o conteúdo quando eu reordeno a lista. Preciso saber se a única forma de resolver esse problema é modificar o valor do objeto quando reordenar a lista e quando for renderizar o componente novamente aplicar um determinado css de acordo com um valor definido no objeto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### ComponenteReordenavel

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import FontAwesome from 'react-fontawesome';
import { Panel } from 'react-bootstrap';
import StrongLabel from '../StrongLabel/StrongLabel';
import PostBet from '../PostBet/PostBet';
import {Col} from 'react-bootstrap';

class ComponenteReordenavel extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isRotated: false,
      chevronStyle:{
        transform: 'rotate(180deg)'
      }
    }
    this.rotateElement    = this.rotateElement.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.chevron).addEventListener('click', this.rotateElement);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
  }

  createPostBet(post, index){
    return <Col key={index} xs={6} md={4}><PostBet nameTime={post.name} valueBet={post.value}></PostBet></Col>;
  }

  createPostBets(posts){
    return posts.map((i, index) => this.createPostBet(i, index));
  }

  rotateElement(){
    this.setState({
      isRotated: !this.state.isRotated,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Bet">
        <div className="HeaderBet">
          <FontAwesome style={this.state.isRotated ? this.state.chevronStyle : {} } ref='chevron' name="chevron-down"/>
          <StrongLabel name={this.props.source.description}></StrongLabel>
          <FontAwesome name="arrows-v" onClick={this.props.onClick}/>
        </div>
        <div className="ListBets">
          <Panel collapsible expanded={!this.state.isRotated}>
                {this.createPostBets(this.props.source.bet)}
          </Panel>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ComponenteReordenavel;
```

Comment: A função render() será chamada quando o state ou props do componente forem modificados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dois problemas que podem ser os responsáveis pelo bug.

Você está usando o índice como `key`. O React utiliza a `key` para realizar seu algoritmo de atualização do `DOM` da forma mais eficiente possível.

Se você muda um componente de posição alterando a sua `key`, já que o índice passa a ser outro o React entende que o primeiro componente foi alterado, mas não entende que ele está na terceira posição agora.

A `key` tem que ser sempre um valor único e identificador do recurso, independente da ordem em que esteja. No seu caso o próprio `post.name` seria mais eficiente que o índice.

Além disso não use `ref` como string. É uma má prática. Use callback sempre.

**Referências:**

- https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html
- https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html